# Consulta en Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Si hago esta consulta en mi base de datos me devuelve lo que necesito, que es, el id del futbolista y el número de temporadas de este deportista en un club, ya sea en el equipo A, B, o juvenil:

```
SELECT idpersona, count(idpersona) FROM (
  SELECT personas.id as idpersona, 
         personas.nombre as nombre, 
         personas.apellido1, 
         equipos.id, 
         plantillas.año as dato 
   FROM `personas`, plantillas, equipos, club_equipo, clubes 
   WHERE personas.id = plantillas.persona_id 
    AND plantillas.equipo_id=equipos.id 
    AND equipos.id=club_equipo.equipo_id 
    AND club_equipo.club_id=clubes.id 
    AND clubes.id=49 
  GROUP BY idpersona, dato 
  ORDER BY idpersona ASC, dato asc
) cuenta 
GROUP BY idpersona 
ORDER BY count(idpersona) desc
```

Es un select anidado, el select interno me agrupa por personas y por el año que está en la plantilla (puede estar en el Madrid A y B en un año pero solo debería contar 1) y después agrupo esos datos y los ordeno.

Al pasarlo a Eloquent hago esto:

```
$nueva = Persona::join('plantillas', 'personas.id', '=', 'plantillas.persona_id')
        ->join('equipos', 'plantillas.equipo_id', '=', 'equipos.id')
        ->join('club_equipo', 'equipos.id', '=', 'club_equipo.equipo_id')
        ->join('clubes', 'club_equipo.club_id', '=', 'clubes.id')
        ->where('clubes.id', $id)
        ->nombre($request->get('nombre'))
        ->distinct()
        ->groupBy('personas.id');
```

Y después la segunda consulta así:

```
  $personas = $nueva->addselect('personas.*', DB::raw('count(personas.id) as cuenta'))
        ->groupBy('personas.id')
        ->orderbyDesc('cuenta')
        ->paginate(40);

    return view('equipo', compact('personas'));
```

Pero tengo dos problemas:

1. Me muestra las personas, pero ha sumado 2 en caso de que jugasen en el Madrid A y B.
2. Cuando pagino me muestra 40, pero la segunda página tiene 2 o 3 que ya estaban en la primera página.

Gracias.

Comment: cuál es el significado de `club_equipo` ? pareciera permitir una relación muchos a muchos entre clubes y equipos pero eso no tiene mucho sentido

Comment: Justo es eso. Un club es una institución que puede tener equipo A, B, C... y a su vez, un equipo podría pertenecer a dos clubes ya que pueden existir fusiones. Gracias.

Comment: Ok entonces la consulta es: "listar quienes pertenecieron alguna vez al club RM y cuantas temporadas" y se considera irrelevante si durante una misma temporada el jugador fue ascendido al primer equipo o castigado y enviado al equipo B

Comment: @ffflabs correcto, listar decrecientemente por número de temporadas en un club, ya fuese el A, B, C o juvenil. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes los clubes

**Club**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 49 | Real Madrid |
| 50 | La Coruña |
| 51 | Barcelona |

Y los equipos

**Equipo**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 31 | Real Madrid A |
| 32 | Real Madrid B |
| 33 | Barcelona A |
| 34 | Barcelona B |

Y una relación entre ellos que refleja la existencia de varios equipos en cada club: el titular, los castigados, los juveniles, etc.

**Club Equipo**

| club_id | equipo_id |
| --- | --- |
| 51 | 29 |
| 49 | 31 |
| 49 | 32 |

Cada uno de esos equipos ve pasar a un conjunto de jugadores durante una temporada. En el ejemplo siguiente el jugador 23 pasó del equipo B al A durante el 2020. El jugador 21 ha jugado en el A las temporadas 2019 y 2020.

**Plantilla**

| persona_id | equipo_id | temporada |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 31 | 2019 |
| 21 | 31 | 2020 |
| 23 | 32 | 2020 |
| 23 | 31 | 2020 |

Como veo que en el resultado final no te importa el nombre del jugador, bastaría sacar el `persona_id` de la plantilla.

Un equipo puede estar asociado a dos clubes debido a una fusión como tú mencionas. En ese caso aparecería dos veces. Sin embargo, el  `WHERE clubes.id = 49` quitará del resultado al otro club.

Tu consulta principal entrega un resultado (antes de agrupar) cuyos campos relevantes son:

| persona_id | equipo_id | temporada | club_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 31 | 2019 | 49 |
| 21 | 31 | 2020 | 49 |
| 23 | 32 | 2020 | 49 |
| 23 | 31 | 2020 | 49 |

`club_id` es redundante porque tú mismo lo pones en el WHERE. `equipo_id` es irrelevante porque en una temporada te puedes pasear por todos los equipos sin cambiar de club. Y la cantidad de temporadas es la cantidad de años *distintos* que queda en el resultado.

La consulta principal, entonces, es

```
SELECT plantillas.persona_id as idpersona, 
     COUNT(distinct plantillas.temporada) AS dato
FROM  plantillas
 JOIN equipos     ON plantillas.equipo_id = equipos.id
 JOIN club_equipo ON equipos.id=club_equipo.equipo_id
 JOIN clubes        ON club_equipo.club_id=clubes.id 
WHERE clubes.id=49 
GROUP BY plantillas.persona_id
```

**Llevándolo a Eloquent**

**nota**: en Laravel 8 tus modelos estarán en `\App\Models\<modelo>`. Acá usé `\App\<modelo>`

El modelo Club (puede que debas ponerle manualmente el nombre de la tabla o asumirá que es `clubs`) tiene una relación `belongsToMany` con `Equipo`  a través de la tabla `club_equipo`, que es sólo de paso y no necesita modelo

```
public function equipos() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(
          \App\Equipo::class, // modelo relacionado
          'club_equipo'  // tabla pivote
   );
}
```

Y en el modelo Equipo

```
public function clubes() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(
          \App\Club::class, // modelo relacionado
          'club_equipo'  // tabla pivote
   );
}
```

En el mismo modelo también tenemos que un equipo tiene muchas plantillas

```
public function plantillas() {
   return $this->hasMany(
          \App\Plantilla::class // modelo relacionado
   );
}
```

Y en el modelo Plantilla la relación inversa

```
public function equipo() {
   return $this->belongsTo(
          \App\Equipo::class // modelo relacionado
   );
}
```

En tu caso las llaves foráneas cumplen con el nombre que Eloquent espera, que es `<modelo_en_minúsculas>_id` así que no necesitas poner explícitamente los nombres de las llaves en esas definiciones.

La consulta que obtiene todas las combinaciones es

```
 $data = Club::with([
     'equipos' => function ($query) {
        $query->with([
            'plantillas' => function($query) {
                $query->select(['persona_id', 'equipo_id','temporada']);
             }
        ]);
     }
 ]);
```

Pero como sólo te interesa el club 49, en vez de traer los resultados como

```
  $resultado = $data->get()
```

usas

```
  $resultado = $data->find(49)
```

La salida en JSON tiene la estructura

```
    {
      "id": 49,
      "nombre": "Real Madrid",
      "equipos": [
          {
            id: 31,
            nombre: "Real Madrid A",
            plantillas: [
               {persona_id: 21, equipo_id: 31, temporada: 2019},
               {persona_id: 21, equipo_id: 31, temporada: 2020},
               {persona_id: 23, equipo_id: 31, temporada: 2020},
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 32,
            nombre: "Real Madrid B",
            plantillas: [
               {persona_id: 23, equipo_id: 32, temporada: 2020},
            ]
          }
         
       ]
    }
```

Puedes obtener solamente el contenido de "equipos" con

```
      $resultado = $data->find(49)->equipos
```

En el array que te queda hay data repetida por ser de equipos distintos, pero en grupos separados, por lo que hay que juntarlas, y lo más eficiente es usar [flatMap](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-flatmap)

```
      $resultado = $data->find(49)->equipos
        ->flatMap(function($equipo) {
           return $equipo['plantillas'];
        });
```

Ahora la salida sería

```
     [
        {persona_id: 21, equipo_id: 31, temporada: 2019},
        {persona_id: 21, equipo_id: 31, temporada: 2020},
        {persona_id: 23, equipo_id: 31, temporada: 2020},
        {persona_id: 23, equipo_id: 32, temporada: 2020},
     ]
```

Un arreglo sobre el cual ahora es viable correr [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-unique) especificando que el criterio es que sean distintos la persona y temporada

```
      $resultado = $data->find(49)->equipos
        ->flatMap(function($equipo) {
           return $equipo['plantillas'];
        })->unique(function($plantilla) {
              return $plantilla->only(['persona_id','temporada]);
        });
```

Esto devuelve el primer registro para cada tupla única

```
     [
        {persona_id: 21, equipo_id: 31, temporada: 2019},
        {persona_id: 21, equipo_id: 31, temporada: 2020},
        {persona_id: 23, equipo_id: 31, temporada: 2020},

     ]
```

Juntando todo, debieras poder obtener lo necesario con

```
   $data = Club::with([
     'equipos' => function ($query) {
        $query->with([
            'plantillas' => function($query) {
                $query->select(['persona_id', 'equipo_id','temporada']);
             }
        ]);
     }
   ])
   ->find(49)->equipos
        ->flatMap(function($equipo) {
           return $equipo['plantillas'];
        })->unique(function($plantilla) {
              return $plantilla->only(['persona_id','temporada]);
        });
```

**Solución de BetaM**

En los comentarios a esta pregunta, [@BetaM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/128299/betam) indica acertadamente que puedo incluir (via `with`) una relación anidada (relación de una relación) usando dot notation. Con esto, nos indica acertadamente que la query principal puede ser mucho más simple:

```
      Club::with([
          'equipos.plantillas' => function ($query) {            
             $query->select(['persona_id', 'equipo_id','temporada']);        
          }
       ])->findOrFail(49); // o find(49)
```

(el uso de `findOrFail` es opcional, depende si prefieren tratar un resultado vacío como excepción y lidiar con él en el catch, o lidiar con el caso en la vista con un `forElse` (creo, no uso blade).

**Ediciones del 18 de enero**

Aunque la solución de arriba queda bastante cerca del objetivo final, hay dos pasos restantes que vale la pena comentar.

El método [countBy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-countBy) de una colección recibe el nombre de un campo X o bien una función. Cuando es lo primero contará los registros que tengan el mismo valor en campo X. Cuando es una función, contará los que tengan el mismo valor para el resultado de la función.

```
   $data_agrupada = $data->countBy('persona_id')

   {
     "21": 2,
     "23": 1
   }
```

El método [forPage($pagina, $cantidad)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-forpage) entrega un `chunk` de la colección correspondiente a los registros de la página `$pagina` si cada página mostrara un máximo de `$cantidad`. (la página 0 y la 1 son iguales, para que puedas mandar el valor desde el front sin tener que restar 1, etc)

```
   // registros 31 al 60
   $data_paginada = $data_agrupada->forPage(2, 30);
```

Hay algunos métodos que reciben una colección y la entregan como array, y ahora no tengo presente cual es cual, pero si se encuentran con un error

> El método XYZ esperaba un array, se recibió una instancia de *Illuminate\Support\Collection*

Significa que deben terminar con el método que devuelve la salida como array

```
    $data_como_array = $data_paginada->all();
```

**Algunos comentarios al margen:**

Siempre que puedan, eviten meter consultas directas es el query builder de Eloquent. Si hacen `Modelo1::whereRaw(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM tabla2...'))` se están perdiendo la oportunidad de que el builder haga sus optmizaciones (cursores, lazy relations, rehidratación, casting y más) y el resultado a simple vista no transmite el propósito de la query.

Comment: para traer un club con sus equipos y cada equipo con sus plantillas. El camino alternativo es definir un scope que encapsule esa query. Eso o bien he estado haciendo todo mal durante meses

Comment: Buenas @ffflabs gracias por la respuesta. La idea es que como dices, te devuelva ese JSON con los datos, pero quiero una lista que me diga los futbolistas, por ejemplo: "Sergio Ramos 14 temporadas", "Zinedine Zidane 13 temporadas", "Marcelo 12 temporadas"... Yo pongo un paginate(40) para que me muestre sus caras ordenado según de más a menos temporadas. Gracias.

Comment: Pero lo probaste? Porque ahí no menciona que la relación pueda ponerse en notación dot. @AngelO si quieres obtener los nombres junto con lo demás mejor tira una query adicional con `whereIn`,`[mapeo de plantilla.id_persona]`creo que te dejé tan bien encaminado como puedo

Comment: @ffflabs muchas gracias. El problema es con la doble query, que al pasarla a Eloquent no me agrupa los equipos. Yo creo que es problema de la segunda consulta que hago, en la que utilizo addselect. Fíjate que yo recupero todo el tiempo el ID con la cuenta de temporadas, que es lo que quiero mostrar. Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: @ffflabs estoy probando y el JSON me muestra todo agrupado correctamente. Lo único, que no sé como hacer para que muestre el número de veces que aparece cada uno porque count me contaría todos los casos. Gracias.

Comment: Después de la transformación `unique(...)` añades `->countBy('persona_id')`

Comment: @ffflabs Genial. Al obtener los datos son de tipo Collection. ¿Cómo podría paginarlos? Gracias.